# Compare two tuple with variable length in Python

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I have two tuples of tuples and I want to compare the values on the basis of their first element

```
list1 = ((1, 2450.0), (2, 2095.0), (4, 1290.0), (5, 1190.0), (6, 1150.0), (7, 1150.0), (8, 1090.0), (9, 1090.0))
list2 = ((1, 2673.0), (4, 1488.0), (5, 1139.0), (6, 1057.0), (7, 1482.0), (8, 1037.0), (9, 1169.0), (10, 937.0))
```

Expected result should be

```
list1 = ((1, 2450.0), (2, 2095.0), (3, nan),(4, 1290.0), (5, 1190.0), (6, 1150.0), (7, 1150.0), (8, 1090.0), (9, 1090.0), (10,nan))
list2 = ((1, 2673.0), (3, nan),(4, 1488.0), (5, 1139.0), (6, 1057.0), (7, 1482.0), (8, 1037.0), (9, 1169.0), (10, 937.0))
```

What would be the efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: The problem is not very well defined. Where did `(3, nan)` come from?

Comment: Sorry. Corrected now.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Also you really need to add more context to your question. What exactly are you doing with the 2 list once you have compared the corresponding tuples? This is essential to answer your question in any meaningful way without having to guess

Comment: Is the `numpy` tag intentional?  You are comparing tuples not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to check if each tuple contain certain numbers which are stored in the first element for each sub-tuple and if the number is not inside create a sub-tuple with the second element equal to None (if nan means None).

I would follow this process, which may not be the most efficient.

```
# Create first a list which contains the desired numbers to be checked
checkTuple = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 )

# Create a function to check if each number is in one of the sub-tuples
def chooseName( checkTuple, randomList ):
    newList = []
    for checkItem in checkTuple:
        itemFound = False
        for item in randomList:
            if checkItem in item:
                numberFound = True
                break
        if numberFound:
            newList.append( checkItem )
        else:
            newList.append( (checkItem, None) )
    return tuple( newList )

# Call the function and take back the tuple
newList1 = chooseName( checkTuple, list1 )
```

Comment: If you are going to answer please format your code to something coherent. Also the OP has not provided enough information to make the assumption you are making.

Comment: Sorry I am a new one and it is the first time.

Comment: Thank you for updating your code. Note there is still an obvious problem that you should correct. The indention according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) should be 4 spaces not 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback!

Comment: Also you do not need to create a list of desired numbers. As in the OPs example it is likely that one will not know all the variables to begin with. So it would be impossible to always know the desired results.